# Unable to transpose Row Data to Columns with ; separated in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

Would you please throw some light on how do I transpose the below data.

```
Create Table Pivot (Empname VARCHAR (10),
Deptno varchar(10),
Salary number (10));

Insert into Pivot (Empname, Deptno, Salary) values ('Max', '10',1000);
Insert into Pivot (Empname, Deptno, Salary) values ('David', '20',2000);
Insert into Pivot (Empname, Deptno, Salary) values ('AD', '30',3000);
```

So output of select query would be

```
EMPNAME DEPTNO SALARY
MAX     10     1000
David   20     2000
AD      30     3000
```

Now the required format in which we need the data is below:

```
Empname Max   David  Ad
Deptno  10    20     30
Sal     1000  2000   3000
```

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+pivot)

Comment: Checkout out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651147/how-to-transpose-column-into-row-in-oracle-sql-11g

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `Conditional Aggregation` with `UNION ALL` :

```
select 'Deptno' as "Empname",
       max( case when Empname = 'Max' then to_number(Deptno) end ) as "Max",
       max( case when Empname = 'David' then to_number(Deptno) end ) as "David",
       max( case when Empname = 'AD' then to_number(Deptno) end ) as "AD"
  from pivot  
union all  
select 'Sal',
       max( case when Empname = 'Max' then Salary end ) ,
       max( case when Empname = 'David' then Salary end ) ,
       max( case when Empname = 'AD' then Salary end )
  from pivot;
```

or another option is using `pivot` clause with `UNION ALL` :

```
select 'Deptno' as "Empname", max("Max") as "Max", max("David") as "David", max("AD") as "AD"
  from pivot   
  pivot( max(to_number(Deptno)) for Empname in ('Max' as "Max",'David' as "David",'AD' as "AD")) 
union all  
select 'Sal', max("Max") as "Max", max("David") as "David", max("AD") as "AD"
  from pivot   
  pivot( max(Salary) for Empname in ('Max' as "Max",'David' as "David",'AD' as "AD"));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=be8de1b8187532d6c14615b89b63c864)</kbd>

Comment: I would be inclined to unpivot first to rows and then aggregate.  Your solution is more efficient.